# In Python, how do I give each member of an Enum its own implementation of an Enum instance method?

Tags: python, oop, enums

I have an Enum instance method whose body consists of an `if` statement with a condition for each of the Enum's members, like

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    INSTANCE_ONE = 1
    INSTANCE_TWO = 2
    
    def myInstanceMethod(self, arg1, arg2):
        if self is MyEnum.INSTANCE_ONE:
            # do some complicated stuff with the args over many lines of code
            ...
        elif self is MyEnum.INSTANCE_TWO:
            # do entirely different complicated stuff with the args
            ...
```

I would consider it more elegant if, instead, each of the Enum's members had its own implementation of `myInstanceMethod`. But is there an elegant way to achieve that syntactically?

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want these to be children of an abstract class rather than members of an Enum?

Comment: @Samwise Yes, I want an enumeration of those.

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/e2thenegpii/19dd5df64227e27639dac16828098e92) may be of interest. Basically, your `myInstanceMethod` is a dispatch method and so you can make use of functools `singledispatchmethod`. However, for that to work, your enumerants must have their own unique types, and so you need metaclasses and other stuff. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it certainly is elegant.

Answer (score 3):

One simple approach would be to use a decorator class to map the name of each enumerated value to the corresponding instance method by storing the mapping in a dict as a class attribute, so that when the wrapped method is called, the mapped function can be called based on the name of the `Enum` instance:

```
class bind:
    bound_methods = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.bound_methods[(func.__qualname__, wrapped_self.name)](wrapped_self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.bound_methods[(func.__qualname__, self.name)] = func
        return wrapper
```

so that:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    INSTANCE_ONE = 1
    INSTANCE_TWO = 2

    @bind('INSTANCE_ONE')
    def myInstanceMethod(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

    @bind('INSTANCE_TWO')
    def myInstanceMethod(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 * arg2

print(MyEnum.INSTANCE_ONE.myInstanceMethod(2, 3))
print(MyEnum.INSTANCE_TWO.myInstanceMethod(2, 3))
```

would output:

```
5
6
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/JuvenileFuzzyStrategy

Comment: One thing I prefer about this approach over one involving `lambda` like in @omzz15's answer is that the method name is alongside the method implementation. On the other hand, things I disprefer include (a) the method implementation is outside of the specification of the Enum member's value, and (b) to understand what's going on requires the code maintainer to understand the advanced concept of decorator classes.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use lambda functions that are stored in each instance of the enum. It would look something like this:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    INSTANCE_ONE = (1, lambda arg1, arg2 : print(arg1 + arg2))
    INSTANCE_TWO = (2, lambda arg1, arg2 : print(arg1 * arg2))

    def myInstanceMethod(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.value[1](arg1, arg2)
```

if you wanted something longer you could use the multi-line lambda like

```
lambda arg1, arg2 : (
    line 1,
    line 2,
    line 3,
    ...
)
```

I hope this helped but if you want to keep the code somewhere else you could also do it by creating global methods and just calling those in your lambda functions

Comment: I thought of something along these lines. One thing I find inelegant about this is that the method name isn't alongside the method implementation.